# Dealing with generic casting

Tags: java, generics

Why does the safety of the cast in `makeArray` bank on whether user gets access to the array created?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private E[] makeArray(int s) {
    return (E[]) new Object[s];
}
```

I'm guessing that the user might be able to use the wrong data type if they get a hold of the array. For example, instead of using `s` type elements, the user instead uses `T` type elements.

Comment: Because the user may store an object that is not of type `E` into the returned array and this will throw `ArrayStoreException` only at **runtime**

Comment: `new Object[s]` does not create an array of `s` type elements. `new Object[s]` creates an array of `Object` **of size `s`**